# Link inside link with vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to make an area of my site that is a link but inside it has another link. By default, when I click in the div, it fire the external link, but when i click on the link inside the div, it continues firing the external link.

[image: Example]

That white box is a link, those arrows are links too. But when i click into the arrows it fires whit box link.

How can I prevent this? I'm using Vue.

[EDIT]

When I click in the arrows, it fires arrows link, but after it fire external box link.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers

Comment: Sure! I don't know how I missed it.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you set up the handler for the arrow, use the [stop](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) modifier.

```
@click.stop="handleArrow"
```